# .getMessagesForThread().getReplyTo() suddenly returns empty values where before it returned the return address

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

For months I have used this little script to auto reply to clients but on may 2 it started returning empty values. Did google change something or did I mess something up?

The body and the subject are still returned as normal. However, reply to email-ID is blank.

Below is the relevant code:

```
 var message = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(label[i]);

    var body = message[0].getPlainBody(); 
    //   Logger.log(body);
    var email = message[0].getReplyTo(); 
       Logger.log(email);
       Logger.log(sub);
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: This could be in response to this [phishing malware](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2017/may/03/google-docs-phishing-attack-malware), maybe damage control? Just to be clear, this my speculation/theory, I could be completely wrong!

Comment: You should report it as an "issue" on the issue tracker.  [Link to Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: I did that at the time. I am really confused, a google script function stops working and nobody knows why. How long will it take for the google team to notice my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function getMail(){

var myspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('*************');
var mysheet = myspreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
//0~99まで
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0 , 500);
var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads); 
var froms = [];
var row = mysheet.getLastRow()+1

messages.get

for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
{
froms.push([messages[i][0].getFrom(),messages[i][0].getSubject()]);
}

mysheet.getRange(mysheet.getLastRow()+1,1,threads.length,2).setValues(froms);
}
```